# Please Solve this problem .... "type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'String"

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
import 'package:e_comaece/widget/back_layer.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:backdrop/backdrop.dart';
    import 'package:carousel_pro_nullsafety/carousel_pro_nullsafety.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_swiper_null_safety/flutter_swiper_null_safety.dart';
    
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      static const routeName = "/home";
    
      const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
    }
    
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      final List<Widget> _CarouselImage = [
        Image.asset('images/caro1.png'),
        Image.asset('images/caro2.png'),
        Image.asset('images/caro3.png'),
        Image.asset('images/caro4.png'),
      ];
    
      final List _swipImage = [
        Image.asset('images/addidas.jpeg'),
        Image.asset('images/apple.jpeg'),
        Image.asset('images/Dell.jpeg'),
        Image.asset('images/h&m.jpeg'),
        Image.asset('images/Huawei.jpeg'),
        Image.asset('images/nike.jpeg'),
        Image.asset('images/samsung.jpeg'),
      ];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: BackdropScaffold(
            headerHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
            appBar: BackdropAppBar(
              title: const Text(
                'EasyBuy',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              leading: BackdropToggleButton(
                icon: AnimatedIcons.home_menu,
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 14,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        "https://cdn1.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/43/20/bearded-man-s-face-hipster-character-fashion-vector-18884320.jpg"),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            backLayer: const BackLayer(),
            frontLayer: ListView(
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Carousel(
                      images: _CarouselImage,
                      autoplay: true,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 5),
                      animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                      indicatorBgPadding: 4,
                      dotSize: 5,
                      boxFit: BoxFit.fill,
                    )),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Popular Brands',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text('view all',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
//type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'String'
                Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Swiper(
                      itemCount: _swipImage.length,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, int i) {
                        return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.grey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          ),
                          child: Image.asset(_swipImage[i]),
                        );
                      },
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't try to bypass the system by pasting code-text, you can learn more about the issue while you'll describe it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is actually quite self-explanatory.
Your code is expecting `_swipImage[i]` to be a List of Strings `List<String>`, instead of a list of image assets `List<AssetImage>`.

Change this code:

```
final List<Widget> _CarouselImage = [
    Image.asset('images/caro1.png'),
    Image.asset('images/caro2.png'),
    Image.asset('images/caro3.png'),
    Image.asset('images/caro4.png'),
  ];

  final List _swipImage = [
    Image.asset('images/addidas.jpeg'),
    Image.asset('images/apple.jpeg'),
    Image.asset('images/Dell.jpeg'),
    Image.asset('images/h&m.jpeg'),
    Image.asset('images/Huawei.jpeg'),
    Image.asset('images/nike.jpeg'),
    Image.asset('images/samsung.jpeg'),
  ];
```

into  a list of Strings, like this:

```
  final List<String> _CarouselImage = [
    'images/caro1.png',
    'images/caro2.png',
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume this is your code.

```
Container(
  child: Swiper(
           itemBuilder: (ctx, init i) {
             return Container(
                      child: Image.asset(_swipImage[i])
                    )
           }
```

Your code using two `Image.asset` in last line.

```
 child: Image.asset(Image.asset('images/addidas.jpeg'))
```

change it to this:

```
Container(
  child: Swiper(
           itemBuilder: (ctx, init i) {
             return Container(
                      child: _swipImage[i],
                    )
           }
```

Comment: can you include some details , it will help others to understand the issue

Comment: your code is `child: Image.asset(_swipImage[i])` the items in `_swipImage` are like this `Image.asset('images/samsung.jpeg')` so your code will be like this: `child: Image.asset(Image.asset('images/samsung.jpeg'))` and this is wrong you use two `Image.asset`.

Comment: yes you are right, can you include this comment part on answer.